# Can storage for references inside a C++ class be optimized away?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization

Does the C++ language allow the following code to print e.g. 1 instead of 16? According to other answers I would guess yes but this case specifically doesn't seem to have been covered.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "cstdlib"
using namespace std;

struct as_array {
    double &a, &b;

    as_array(double& A, double& B)
        : a(A), b(B) {}

    double& operator[](const int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return this->a;
            break;
        case 1:
            return this->b;
            break;
        default:
            abort();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << sizeof(as_array) << endl;
}
```

Comment: *"but this case specifically doesn't seem to have been covered"* - what specifically about your case do you feel wasn't covered?  Just that the references are class members?

Comment: Am I missing something? Since `a` and `b` are independent references, how would the compiler implement the struct, other than by allocating space for two pointers?

Comment: > what specifically about your case do you feel wasn't covered?

yeah it was the fact that the references are class members

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Standard says under [dcl.ref]:

> It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage

Also it is up to the compiler to decide what the size of an object is, so you could get any non-zero number here.

There is also the as-if rule (aka. permission to optimize). So it would be legal for the compiler to use storage for these references if and only if the way the references were used required it.

Having said all that; in the interests of having a stable ABI I would still expect that a compiler assigns storage to these references.

Answer (score 2):

The way the compiler implements reference behaviours - including where and how they're stored - is not specified in the C++ Standard.  Consequently, some compiler could "print e.g. 1 instead of 16" as you ask.

Separately, you don't need to `break` after `return`ing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that

```
cout << sizeof(as_array) << endl;
```

always returns the required storage for two pointers to double on the given machine, maybe extended with gaps to fulfill packing rules. Optimizing did mot mean to reduce the size of the storage of given data structures. Instead the compiler can optimize your code completely away in a real world scenario. So if you have the code:

```
double a=100;
double b=200;
as_array arr(&a, &b);
std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
```

can result in optimizing the storage for the struct completely away, because the compiler knows how the values are handled through your code. But the print out of sizeof(arr) still give you the theoretical size of the struct.

Anyway: If you want to get better optimizing results, you should write better code! Make methods `const` if they are `const`! If you use c++11 use constexpr if possible.

Comment: What leads you to believe that?

Comment: The definition of the struct is in a first step independent from the usage. So if you "ask" the compiler for that theoretical size, what should be optimzed in this case? There is nothing which can be optimized away without knowing the use case. I am not a language lawyer but how should the given size optimized without knowing anything else?